How did Confirmafy manage to send Whatsapp templates without pre-approval process?
I'm developing an application similar to Confirmafy that uses the WhatsApp Business API to send messages to users. According to WhatsApp's documentation, message templates need to be pre-approved, and line breaks are not allowed within variables.
However, I've noticed that Confirmafy allows users to edit the message body, including adding line breaks, and the message is sent instantly without any apparent approval process. Here’s an example of how the message configuration looks in Confirmafy
In this configuration, I can insert line breaks and any text, and the message is delivered instantly via WhatsApp. This behavior seems to contradict WhatsApp's official documentation.
How does Confirmafy manage to send messages with line breaks in variables without needing pre-approval from WhatsApp?
Is there a specific API endpoint or method that bypasses the template approval process?
Are there any exceptions or special permissions required to achieve this functionality?
I already talked to Twilio and Meta support and they can´t help me. Someone know hoy can I do this? Thanks

You mention the old "WhatsApp templates" here. Using them is quite strict and trivial-appearing whitespaces or encodings can turn a valid usage of a template invalid.
So I'd suggest using the Content Template Builder. In there, you can submit another kind of template to Meta and from then on, reference the template by ID. Some of these templates are instantly usable in user-initiated conversations after creating them. They only need to be approved to be used in business-initiated conversations.
Maybe that's what they do.
Docs
WhatsApp Legacy Templates versus Content Templates

Hello IObert, thanks for your reply. The thing is that when I update the message body on Confirmafy (see image above) and then I click on receive a message I receive it instantly and it's a business-initiated conversation, you think they are using a Content Template for that? I don't understand how I can add space lines on Content Template variables and the message is received instantly. Is there a way you can add place lines on variables?

No, I'm afraid you can't add multiple lines in one variable. The explanation above only works for user-initiated conversations. I'm not sure how they do it otherwise.

You think maybe they are using something like wwebjs? You know if its legal to use it?

I am not aware of wwebjs, sorry
